# Querying files in a storage account in Azure

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I would like to know what are the ways I can Query a large set of my logs files stored in my storage account. Kusto Query most of the time Times-out so cant use ADX/log-analytics on top of Storage account. What are the other ways we have? Can i link it with Synapse Analytics and use SPARK to query it? Can i have some links to good docs for starting guidance.

Comment: Could you please provide more details like what is the size of data you are querying? After how long you are getting time-out?

Comment: say I have 15 TB of data stored in Storage account